# dynamic record type id getting error Method does not exist incorrect signature: [Schema.DescribeSObjectResult].getRecordTypeInfoByName()

Tags: record-type, dynamic, schema

how to get recordtype id from schema
i am using this

```
Id RecType = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfoByName().get('Booked Stage Read Only').getRecordTypeId();

//Error is Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Schema.DescribeSObjectResult].getRecordTypeInfoByName()

if(BigMachinesQuoteMap.get(bigQuote.id).Order_Number__c != null && BigMachinesQuoteMap.get(bigQuote.id).BigMachines__Is_Primary__c == true)
            {
                BigMachinesQuoteMap.get(bigQuote.id).Booked_Order_Amount__c;
                opp[0].StageName = 'Booked';
                opp[0].RecordTypeId=RecType;
            }

            }
            update opp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name is `getRecordTypeInfosByName` (has an `s` in it) not `getRecordTypeInfoByName` that you have. See e.g. [RecordTypeInfo Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) for code examples.